# How to grab an HTML link from a table?

Tags: google-sheets

Behind each of the company names [here](http://www.nasdaq.com/markets/ipos/activity.aspx?tab=upcoming) is an HTML link to another page.

How do I import that HTML link into Google Sheets?

Comment: What did you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull in those links with this formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.nasdaq.com/markets/ipos/activity.aspx?tab=upcoming","//tr/td[1]/a/@href")
```